# What do we do about platform-specific questions?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Due to the nature of robotics, there are multiple relevant robotics platforms in existence (MOOS, ROS, YARP, etc).  When we permute these platforms with other available libraries (computer vision, graph optimization, point clouds, etc), the question-space becomes quite large, with lots of available questions, like:

- Does component **X** work with platform **Y**?
- Why is **X** (my platform of choice) better than all of the other platforms?

What should the community policy be on moderating questions of this nature?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly we should try to use tagging to make it easy for people to filter for or filter out things they are or are not interested in.

Secondly, we need to be proactive in editing, commenting, flagging and voting to close inappropriate questions.

*Why is X (my platform of choice) better than all of the other platforms?* is simple **not constructive** and all questions of this type should be **closed** as soon as possible, reminding people that [Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask)

Meanwhile *Does component X work with platform Y?* is much **less constructive** than *When I try to use component X work with platform Y I have problem Z* and so the latter should be preferred. In this case we should encourage people to **edit questions** to make them **more constructive**.

This is the way we build a strong community of experts willing and able to share their experience and knowledge and this is the way we encourage a strong, vibrant community of people who ask interesting and relevant questions.

Answer (score 4):

I would consider this closely tied to whether a question already has an answer that five minutes on Google would yield. If so, that would in general be not be considered suited for this site.

If for some reason the answer isn't Google-able, that would seem to me the sort of expert opinion this site is designed for.

Comment: Be careful here because you want to be Google-able; this definition is self-defeating.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain my wording was unclear. Does this clarify my idea?