# The 7 Essential Meta Questions for Robotics Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, 7-questions

Given the [The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) I think it is worth having a place where we can link together these essential meta questions.

The 7 Essential Questions of Every Beta are:

1. Are questions about [subject] on or off topic?

   - See the [on-topic](/questions/tagged/on-topic) tag, for example:
   - [“Current state” questions](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/91/37)
   - [Should I ask specific ROS questions here instead of answers.ros.org? (same applies for other libraries)](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35/37)
   - [Should I ask questions I already know the answer to in order to shape the site?](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/55/37)
   - [Do solely software questions belong here?](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28/37)
   - [Can someone ask a vendor-specific question?](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26/37)
   - [How do we address questions about related subject areas?](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5/37)
   - [What do we do about platform-specific questions?](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/37)
2. What should our FAQ contain?

   - See [What should our FAQ contain?](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19/37)
   - See also questions tagged with [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) and [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) tag.
3. How should we tag questions about {subject}?

   - See the [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging), [tag-synonyms](/questions/tagged/tag-synonyms) and [retagging](/questions/tagged/retagging) tags, for example:
   - [Should we add drone as a tag synonym for uav?](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/92/37)
   - [Tag: ultrasound vs sonar](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/53/37)
   - [Request to create synonym for not-exactly-c tag](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/140/37)
4. Who should the moderators be?

   - See [Who should our beta moderators be?](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/84/37)
   - See also questions tagged with the [moderation](/questions/tagged/moderation) tag.
5. What’s the “elevator pitch” for our site?

   - See [What’s the “elevator pitch” for our site?](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20/37)
   - See also [What should we put in our about page?](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/155/37)
6. What should our logo and site design look like?

   - See [What should the theme and layout look like?](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8/37)
   - See also [What logo should we use after beta phase?](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208/what-logo-should-we-use-after-beta-phase)
7. How do we promote our site?

   - See [Promoting this website](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/46/37)
   - See also [Help promote Robotics with Community Promotion Ads - 2013](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/149/37) and questions tagged with the [site-promotion](/questions/tagged/site-promotion) tag.

Comment: Good idea! Centralize ALL THE THINGS. :D

Comment: @rsegal - I'm not sure whether that is sarcasm or appreciation. *8')  As much as anything, this is a placeholder so it's easy to remember which of these questions we have created one or more discussions for. I will try to keep it up to date as new meta questions are added.

Comment: Appreciation all the way. It's a great bookeeping idea.

Comment: You may want to link point 1 to `[meta-tag:on-topic]`. That centralization becomes useful when we want to hone our FAQ.

Comment: One moderator post, coming riiight up! http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/84/who-should-our-beta-moderators-be

Comment: @Mark Could you accept/decline the nomination?

Comment: @MarkBooth: Ah. Ninja-mode, I see :P