# What should we put on our about page?

Tags: discussion

Since we have a nice [about page](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/about) and the top section can be edited by moderators in the same way that the [What kind of questions can I ask here?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) FAQ entry [can be edited](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22/37), I was wondering what we want to put in there.

The default contents are:

> **Robotics** is a question and answer site for professional robotic engineers, hobbyists, researchers and students. It's built and run *by you* as part of the [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com) network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about robotics.

If you have any suggestions about how we could improve our about page, it would be great if you would post an answer with your proposed *about* content.

---

Before posting a suggestion, I would highly recommend reading [Shog9's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164779) to the question [What should we put on our About page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164778) over on [meta stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: I've added this question to our [7 Essential Meta Questions for Robotics Stack Exchange](http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/q/18/37) *question*.

Comment: To me, the default text looks good enough :)

Answer (score 1):

The default is very informative, but it might be interesting to see if we can remove the unicorn question and add a more relevant question. Otherwise it looks a little generic. Other SE sites do this, as far as I know.

Comment: While we are in beta, I believe that only the "Robotics is" section can be edited, just like many [other areas of the site](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/faq#sketchy).

Comment: Note that now we have more content, the *Unicorn* question has now been replaced by a more representative question.