# What’s the “elevator pitch” for our site?

Tags: discussion

From the [The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/):

---

### What’s the “elevator pitch” for our site?

Imagine you’ve just gotten on an elevator with a friendly stranger. You have precisely one floor to describe your community to them. What would you say? The elevator pitch is a brief sentence that describes *what your site is about*. Every word counts!

Once decided, it can be sliced and diced to form:

- the tagline
- the motto
- the blurb under the logo
- a convenience redirect “nickname” for the site
- perhaps eventually the domain name in some form

(Due to a variety of [practical difficulties with domain names](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/), we prefer to de-emphasize domain name selection. Most sites will retain their `topic.stackexchange.com` names indefinitely.)

Naming is hard — *really* hard. But if you can come up with a sensible elevator pitch for your community, it’s a great starting point.

For more detail see: [Stack Exchange Naming for Dummies](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/stack-exchange-naming-for-dummies/)

Comment: I've added this question to our [7 Essential Meta Questions for Robotics Stack Exchange](http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/q/18/37) *question*.

Answer (score 1):

- Tagline: Building a robot can take a village. Get your robotics questions answered at robotics.SE!
- Motto: Building better robots, together.
- Blurb: We're a free, community-driven Q&A resource for robotics questions that transcend individual engineering and science disciplines or are heavily influenced by their robotics-based implementation.
- Nickname: robots
- Domain name: positronicbrain, positron, some variant thereof.