# Can someone ask a vendor-specific question?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

After I've been for last two hours on meta or main site, I haven't grasp exact scope of questions for this site. So I will be more specific.

I work with [Fanuc robots](http://www.fanucrobotics.com/) but as I am novice in this field, I would like to ask questions on the vendor-specific robot. For example, how can I synchronize imaging system with the robot, or why the robot is sending wrong encoder value? Are these questions right ones for this site?

Answer (score 7):

Absolutely, we would love vendor specific questions.

We want this site to be at the top of google search results every time you ask a robotics related question and the only way to get *Fanuc* experts coming here are for there to be *Fanuc* questions for them to answer, ditto for any other robot manufacturer.

All we ask is for you to submit [practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) - that's the way we build a strong, successful and growing stack exchange community.