# What are our frequently asked questions on meta?

Tags: discussion, tags

According to our [Robotics FAQ](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/faq)

> [...] our [meta-discussion site](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/) hosts a section of constantly evolving **[frequently asked questions](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq)** that document everything about the site

Unfortunately, so far there are no meta questions tagged [faq](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq). So, is it too early yet for us to consider any questions frequent, or should we randomly tag some existing questions, or should we vote on which questions merit the faq tag?

Comment: I thought it's on this page: http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=faq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nah, we don't need it yet. Most sites don't need the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) unless they have some large policies/how-tos. We shall probably be able to fit most of our policies in  [`/faq`](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/faq).

For example, see [the tag on meta.chem](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq). We've got one post of site promo, one post for a homework policy, one for a TeX tutorial, and one guide for closevoting. Currently, all we have is [this promo post](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46/promoting-this-website) on Robotics. We could make the closevoting guide. The HW policy post makes no sense to be here, and we probably don't need the TeX guide (we have MathJax enabled, but we may not be using it as much).

On the other hand, RaspberryPi.SE has an [empty faq tag](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq).

On the Internet, FAQ has come to mean much more than Frequently Asked Questions. It means "hey, newbie, read this!".

If there are any policies we keep needing to link to, then it may be a good idea to use the faq tag. For now, I'd say we're good :)

Most of the faq pages can be found [on the mother meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq).

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, we only have the community moderation team to help moderate *Robotics*, but we are [currently looking](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/84/37) for [moderators pro tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) of our own.

Once protem moderators have been recruited, it should be easier for us to manage which meta questions need tagging with moderator only tags like [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) and [featured](/questions/tagged/featured). Since [Manishearth mentioned it](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/129/37) I have already added a [How can I format mathematical expressions here, using MathJax?](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/130/37) question and given it the [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) tag to suggest that this might be worthy of a [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag.