# How can I format mathematical expressions here, using MathJax?

Tags: discussion, faq, formatting, mathjax

Blatantly ripped off from [chem.SE](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/86), this post is meant to help people understand how to use MathJax formatting of mathematical expressions here on *Robotics*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Getting started with MathJax

On *Robotics Stack Exchange*, we use [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) to format mathematical expressions. MathJax is a tool that lets us display LaTeX expressions on a browser.

To use MathJax, enclose your mathematical expressions within single(`$...$`) or double(`$$...$$`) dollar signs. Single dollar signs make the expression *inline*, for example, `Let $x$ be a variable` gives:

> Let $x$ be a variable.

On the other hand, double dollar signs make the expression a block element. It gets its own line, and is slightly larger. For example, `The equation of motion is as follows: $$v=u+at$$ It is a SUVAT equation` gives:

> The equation of motion is as follows: $$v=u+at$$ It is a SUVAT equation

Note that the extra spaces in LaTeX do not render, use `\:` or `~` for a space.

---

### Basic MathJax

#### Superscripts and subscripts

You can denote superscripts via the `^` character, and subscripts via `_`. For example, `x^2` renders as $x^2$, `x_1` renders as $x_1$, and `x_1^3` renders as $x_1^3$.

If you want to include more than one character in the super/sub script, enclose it in curly braces (`{...}`).

For example, `x^10` renders as $x^10$, but `x^{10}` renders as $x^{10}$

To put superscripts before the symbol, do this: `{^{a}R_{b}}` which renders as: ${^{a}R_{b}}$

#### Fractions and square roots

Fractions can be easily displayed using `\frac{..}{..}`. For example, `\frac{a+b^c}{de+f}` renders as $\frac{a+b^c}{de+f}$

Protip: You can exclude the braces for single-character numerators/denominators (if the first character is a letter, you need to use a space after `\frac`, though). For example `\frac12` renders as $\frac12$, and `\frac ab` renders as $\frac ab$

Square roots can be added in a similar manner, via `\sqrt{....}`. For example, `\sqrt{x+y}` renders as $\sqrt{x+y}$.

#### Embellishments

`\dot{x} \hat{y} \bar{h} \overrightarrow{v} J^\dagger J^{+} T^\top z' a^{\circ}` render as:

$\dot{x}$ $\hat{y}$ $\bar{h}$ $\overrightarrow{v}$ $J^\dagger$ $J^{+}$ $T^\top$ $z'$ $a^{\circ}$

#### Matrices and vectors

Row vectors are easy enough. `$[xyz]$ $(xyz)$` render as: $[xyz]$ $(xyz)$  But you might want to use a space separator.  `$[1,2,3]$ $[x~y~z]$ $(x~y~z)$` render as: $[1,2,3]$ $[x~y~z]$ $(x~y~z)$

Column vectors are done like this. `\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{bmatrix}` render as:

$$\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}~~\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{bmatrix}$$

2D matrices can also have parentheses or brackets by using `pmatrix` or `bmatrix` accordingly.  Here is the structure:

```
\begin{bmatrix}    
r_{11} & r_{12} & r_{13}\\
r_{21} & r_{22} & r_{23}\\
r_{31} & r_{32} & r_{33}
\end{bmatrix}
```

$$
\begin{bmatrix}    
r_{11} & r_{12} & r_{13}\\
r_{21} & r_{22} & r_{23}\\
r_{31} & r_{32} & r_{33}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

#### Operations

`\otimes \cdot \in \circ \bullet` render as: $\otimes$ $\cdot$ $\in$ $\circ$ $\bullet$

#### Greek letters

Greek letters can be added usung a backslash (`\`), followed by the name of the letter. Captialise the first letter of the name for greek capital letters.

Eg `\alpha \beta \gamma \delta \Omega \Delta` renders as $\alpha$ $\beta$ $\gamma$ $\delta$ $\Omega$ $\Delta$.

Make sure that you put spaces after these if you are typing normal alphabet characters. Eg `e^{\pii}` gives an error, you need to use `e^{\pi i}` for $e^{\pi i}$.

Note that there are special commands `\varepsilon \varsigma \varrho \varpi` to distinguish between the lunate Greek letters ($\varepsilon$ $\varsigma$ $\varrho$ $\varpi$ rather than $\epsilon$ $\sigma$ $\rho$ $\pi$).

#### Misc. Symbols

`\nabla \infty \partial` renders as $\nabla$ $\infty$ $\partial$

#### Font stuff

`boldsymbol` and `mathbf` have slightly different results:  for example: `\boldsymbol{x} \mathbf{x}` render as: $\boldsymbol{x}$ $\mathbf{x}$

Another fancy font: `\mathbb{R}` renders as: $\mathbb{R}$

### Further reading

- [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/9281) (over on [Mathematics stack exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) meta)
- [Wikipedia TeX help page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Displaying_a_formula) (extremely useful as a reference, useless as a tutorial)
- [Harvard intro to TeX](http://www.math.harvard.edu/texman/)
- [LaTeX wikibook, Math section](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics)
- [LaTeX wikibook, Advanced Math section](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics)

Thanks to [Manishearth](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/126/manishearth) for the [chem.SE answer](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/88) on which this is based.