# What's the new approach / policy explanation for shopping questions?

Tags: discussion

I'm not sure what to do with [What languages and platforms exist for multicopter development?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/1855/350) (formerly [Cheapest MultiCopter Development Platform Starting points](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/1850/350), now deleted).

Literally a week before SE's [recent changeover of closing functionality](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/), I had [looked into what our most-closed questions looked like](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/180/350) and noted that shopping questions were a large chunk of them -- but I considered things like "what products are available to solve my problem" to be shopping questions.

Now that SE has lumped shopping questions into "opinion based" questions, I'm not sure if my classification still applies.  Where is the most up-to-date explanation of what constitutes a shopping question (specifically, whether "what products are available to solve my problem" is allowed)?

Answer (score 2):

In general, list questions still make poor Stack Exchange questions. They suffer from many of the problems that Shopping Questions suffer (they get out of date, they generate speculation and discussion, and it is difficult to say definitively *when* they have been answered).

As I said to cMFG when I put his/her question on hold, we prefer *practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face*. In the end I closed it as an **Unbounded Design Question** (which may be familiar as [you suggested it](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/180/37) *8') as I think that is a good way to describe this kind of question:

> **Unbounded Design Questions** are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given design problem, so questions that ask for a list of approaches or a subjective recommendation on a method (for how to build something, how to accomplish something, what something is capable of, etc.) are off-topic.

Comment: Aah OK, so list questions are more "too broad" than "opinion based".  I was looking in the wrong place.