# When closing shopping questions, are they offtopic or opinion based?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I've seen an influx of shopping-style questions lately:

- Where can I buy _____?
- What options for ______ are available?
- Is there a cheaper version of ______?

Since the field of robotics involves *actual* shopping (versus something like mathematics or programming), I'd imagine that the majority of StackExchange sites don't concern themselves with shopping when it comes to defining "opinion-based" questions.

In other words, could we explicitly list shopping questions in [the list of questions to NOT ask on robotics.se](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)?

Answer (score 4):

To answer the question in the title. Shopping questions should be closed as "Opinion based" with a comment to explain what we mean by that.

We have a limited number of [off-topic close reasons](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/179/37), so although we originally had a *Shopping question* close reason, we had to [remove it](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/191/37) to make way for others.

As to the question in the body text, sadly we can't edit [dont-ask](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) help center page, we can only edit [on-topic](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page, so you should direct people there.

We do have [Copy-pastable comment text for common problems with questions?](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176) though, and one specifically to deals with [shopping questions](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/177/37).

Answer (score 1):

Now that the "shopping based" site SE Hardware Recommendations is in commit phase, would it be possible to set up a question migration path to that site?

Admittedly, that would depend on SE Hardware Recommendation mods being willing to accept Robotics hardware recommendations. In addition, I fully appreciate that some Robotics purchases do not strictly fall under the *Hardware* umbrella.

---

#### Update 20160327

Hardware Recommendations is now in Public Beta, and has been for a few months.