# Shopping recommendation not listed as cause for closure

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign

I've found that, on posts I vote to close, the top reason I vote to close is that they are shopping recommendation questions. There is no shopping recommendation pre-canned selection, though, so I usually wind up selecting "life questions" because I feel that the line "what project to start next" is most similar to "where can I buy X".

I think that a specific shopping recommendation tag would make it more clear that they are not allowed because it would show up in the admin tag when the question gets put on hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [this answer](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/191/37) to [What should our list of close reasons look like?](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179) the *Primarily Opinion based* close reason should be used for *shopping* questions.

We only have three close reasons, and the existing close reasons are all more important than an explicit *shopping recommendation* close reason.

Even so, I try to comment with the *Shopping questions* [Copy-pastable comment text](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/177/37) whenever I close one as *Primarily Opinion Based*. That way we get the best of both worlds (not using up a valuable off-topic close reason slot) and people get more direction than an uncommented on POB close.