# Can we add the Robotics Stack Exchange Question Checklist to the Help Center?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

The [Robotics Stack Exchange question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1302/robotics-stack-exchange-question-checklist) post on this Meta looks really useful.

What would it take to move it into the [help asking documentation](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/asking)?

It's hard to find that Meta post for regular users from the main site. I only found this by a direct link from an experienced user. I had actively looked for similar content, but only in the help section, not the meta.

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me.  (But I don't know how to do it).

Answer (score 1):

I put the "status-review" tag on this question which should get the attention of a CM.  (As per this post: https://stackoverflow.com/c/moderators/questions/3381/3607#3607)

Also, we<sup>1</sup> can edit the top text of this page: https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help ourselves.  For example, see how StackApps modified theirs: https://stackapps.com/help.

<sup>1</sup> Not sure if it is just moderators or anyone over a certain reputation.

Comment: Just a note, some parts of the help center can be edited by mods, but regular users cannot edit them at all, so you might also use this question to gather some ideas from the community for the introduction text on the help center. Also, perhaps it's better to replace the mod-only Teams link with [the same public Meta Stack Exchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642/241919). (Also, feel free to delete this comment after it's no longer needed :)

Comment: Is there any way to escalate this? I'm hoping to come and put a bunch more effort into this site. But I need to know that we'll be able to update things in a timely manner as the community grows.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about this.  I just changed the header text on https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help.  I know its not great, but the links below it are pretty good.  If you have something else you want to say there, I'm happy to add it.

Comment: Thanks for doing that at least. It will at least get some more visibility for now. I'll definitely have some more suggestions as I explore the site more.

Answer (score 1):

Our ability to edit the help pages is limited, but building on [Bens changes](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1415/37) to the [Robotics help](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help) landing page, I think we now have as close a solution as is possible without site customisation, which is unlikely.

Originally, [Robotics Stack Exchange question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1302/robotics-stack-exchange-question-checklist) Was written as a link you could post in response to an unclear or poorly written question to help it get improved rather than just voting to close outright. This is why many of the [Copy-pastable comment text for common problems with questions](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/177/37) include something along the lines of

> Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.

Answer (score 1):

The list is indeed very helpful and I was going to suggest adding a link to this on the [Help](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help) page as it was already suggested and done.

I wouldn't recommend adding a new article to the ["asking" section of the help center](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/asking) since it would just split useful information across several pages instead of condensing it in a single one, and it wouldn't be any more visible than the current Meta post is. Adding it to the "How to ask" article is not a possibility because that article is the same across the network, so it'd break it for other sites. And overriding it locally would mean more extra work if wanted to change the page, since we wouldn't be able to do so network-wide. And the [Robotics Stack Exchange question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1302/robotics-stack-exchange-question-checklist) wouldn't be helpful for all the other sites across SE as the information is not suitable to the subject of the other sites.

So since we already have the link in the [Help Center](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help) I think we are good here.