# Is CNC really of topic?

Tags: discussion

Recently, this [question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/21020/how-to-convert-2d-autocad-drawing-into-code-for-cnc-machine-laser-cutter) was closed as of topic.
It is referencing a CNC controller. So, are CNC related questions off topic? Why is there a CNC tag then?

Furthermore, if one reads the question it becomes clear, that the OP wanted to convert a 2D drawing to G-Code. To my knowledge, G-Code is relevant also for the robotics community, as there are robot models, which are programmed using G-Code (Mitsubishi robots, if I am not mistaking).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think CNC is off-topic, but that question asked specifically:

> My question is that is there a software that could read an AutoCAD design or any DWG file and produce a CNC program for 2D profiling? Preferably at free of cost. (Broke student here) Thanks in advance.

From the [Q&A is Hard, Let's Go Shopping](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) post that Ben linked (and is in the [standard closing template](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/177/9720)):

> Here’s one way to ask:
>
> Q: What’s the best low light point-and-shoot camera?
>
> A: Canon S90 and Lumix LX3.
>
> Here’s another way to ask:
>
> Q: How do I tell which point-and-shoot cameras take good low light photos?
>
> A: I strongly recommend looking for something with
>
> - a fast lens (2.0 at least)
> - reasonable ISO handling (at least 400, but preferably 800)
> - the biggest sensor available
>
> The sum of these factors are really critical for low light situations.
>
> The former question provides the path of least resistance: a laundry list of products I can buy without thinking about it too much. But that answer will only be valid for a year at best. The latter question may take some thinking, but its answer will be valid forever … or at least until camera technology somehow shifts beyond lenses and sensors as we know them today. Thus, when it comes to shopping questions, don’t ask us what you should buy — ask us what you need to learn to tell what you should buy.
>
> If I had to summarize our network in a single word, **that word is “learning”**. People come to our sites to learn about topics they are passionate about. As the old Chinese proverb goes, “Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime.” Every question and answer ultimately should be about teaching and learning — yes, even the shopping ones.

So it's not that questions about CNC are off-topic, but that the OP for that question asked for free software. It wasn't a question about how a CNC machine builds a command queue, or what kind of code runs a CNC machine, it was a question that OP could have [just
googled instead](https://www.google.com/search?&q=free+dwg+to+gcode+converter). The number two result there for me is the list of free software you provided in your answer.

Comment: OK, it seems that I was mislead by the comment, which suggested to re-post the question to Engineering SE, suggesting that there is no problem with the questions itself, but the topic.

Comment: Yup,. as written, it was clearly a shopping question, however with a little tweaking, I made it a valid question for *Robotics*. I know it has already been re-opened, and answered, but the fewer [broken windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory) we have, the better.