# What URL should the "MathJax help" link on the Editing Help page point to?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community, mathjax

The [LaTeX section of the Editing Help page](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex) contains the following link:

> Learn more: [MathJax help](https://legacy-www.math.harvard.edu/texman/).

Recently, a Stack Exchange Community Manager has reached out to us to explain that this link can be customized, and asked if we want to change the URL that this "MathJax help" link points to.

Some sites have made meta posts with their own MathJax help tailored to their own community.  And others have just linked to [Mathematics's post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

**What URL do we want the "MathJax help" link to point to for our site?**

- Should we keep the [original URL](https://legacy-www.math.harvard.edu/texman/)?
- Should we link to [Mathematics' MathJax guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)?
- Should we link to this reference post on our meta:
  [How can I format mathematical expressions here, using MathJax?](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130/how-can-i-format-mathematical-expressions-here-using-mathjax)
- Should we make a new post on our meta, and link to that?

Comment: Since this never got escalated to us again after the initial discussion here, I've added the [status-review] tag to it myself. :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, now that I know we have [our own MathJax help post](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130/how-can-i-format-mathematical-expressions-here-using-mathjax), I guess we should just link to that.

Comment: The "MathJax help" link on Robotics.SE (and this Meta site) has been changed to point to [this Robotics Meta post](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130/how-can-i-format-mathematical-expressions-here-using-mathjax), per your suggestion. Let us know if you encounter any problems!

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I think the [*Mathematics.SE* meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is great and we should just use that.  The only reason I can think of why we might want to make our own is if there were special symbols or things we need here in *Robotics* that are more obscure and not covered by theirs.  But I can't really think of any.

That being said, the *Mathematics.SE* meta post is very thorough.  For those who basically know Latex or MathJax and just need a little reminder, a simple cheat sheet with a few common expressions would be nice.  For example, vectors, matrices, and transforms (with superscripts and subscripts).

Comment: I echo Ben's answer...

Answer (score 2):

The other option is to link people to our own [Getting started with MathJax](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/131/37) post, which is based on the [chem.SE](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/88) equivalent.

The [math.se](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/9281) post is very comprehensive, but I can't help but feel that it is so dense that it is more likely to put people off using MathJax than encourage them to do so.

Tailored to our own community, it could be a great introduction to LaTeX for Roboticists who haven't come across it before, and giving people references to learn more is a great way to feed them the infomation they need, when they need it.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that we had our own.  It would be nice to keep people in the *Robotics* site.  But we should expand on that post slightly with examples of vectors and matrices.

Comment: Sounds good to me. While I was actively editing it, it floated to the top of Meta, but obviously it started getting buried as soon as I stopped. It was written in a way that should make it easily extensible.