# Twitter feed now available

Tags: discussion

Robotics.StackExchange now has [its own Twitter feed](https://twitter.com/StackRobotics) (thanks Manish)

To (as they say) join the conversation, please follow `@StackRobotics`

Follows, retweets etc are welcomed and encouraged