# Help promote Robotics with Community Promotion Ads - 2014

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

It has been suggested that we submit a [Community Promotion Ad on Electronics Stack exchange](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2515/3774) and possibly other stack exchange sites. I think this would be a great idea, but my creative skills are limited, so I thought I would ask for suggestions here.

Here is a copy of the guidelines from *electronics*:

---

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- useful tools or resources for electronics work
- interesting articles or findings for the curious
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

---

If anyone has any suggestions for which other sites where we might want to place community ads, comment on this discussion.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been superceded by https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1393/37

Answer (score 5):

[image: robotics stack exchange]

Comment: Thanks to [Daniel T. McDonald](http://www.elfwood.com/~captainzero/GIR-2.0.2597782.html) for placing this image in the public domain.

Comment: For those who don't recognise the reference, [GIR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invader_Zim#Characters) is [Invader Zim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invader_Zim)'s malfunctioning robot.

Comment: I have posted this to [electronics](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/2542/3774) where it currently has enough votes, and both [scifi](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/2552/1461) and [Programmers](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/5474/22493) where it doesn't.

Comment: 2014: [electronics](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/3249/3774), [scifi](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/3250/1461), [programmers](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6318/22493), [android](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/a/1608/4229), [arqade](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/8059/8557), [physics](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/5286/5445) & [superuser](http://meta.superuser.com/a/7448/16858)

Answer (score 4):

[image: robotics stack exchange]

Comment: Thanks to [Sasha](http://www.clker.com/clipart-188290.html) for placing this image in the public domain.

Comment: For those who don't recognise the reference, see [Marvin the paranoid android](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvin_the_Paranoid_Android#Radio_and_TV_series).

Comment: I have posted this to [electronics](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/2541/3774) where it currently has enough votes, and both [scifi](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/2551/1461) and [Programmers](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/5473/22493) where it doesn't.

Comment: 2014: [electronics](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/3248/3774), [scifi](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/3249/1461), [programmers](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6317/22493), [android](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/a/1607/4229), [arqade](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/8058/8557), [physics](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/5285/5445) & [superuser](http://meta.superuser.com/a/7447/16858)

Answer (score 3):

[image: Robotics, now available on Stack Exchange]

Comment: The source image is NOT in the public domain, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm not happy about using unlicensed images myself, but if you want to post this to any stack exchange sites' *Community Promotion Ads* post, just drop a comment here mentioning where you put it.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Be part of the Robot Revolution on Robotics Stack Exchange]

Comment: Both images used are licenced under creative commons. Here is [the cat](http://www.flickr.com/photos/gymking/6200199323/) and [the robot](http://www.flickr.com/photos/glamhag/4954072073/).

Comment: Cool, thanks danijar, that looks great.

Answer (score 0):

[image: robotics stack exchange (image by Evan-Amos)]

Comment: Thanks to [Evan-Amos](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Evan-Amos) for sharing the image [via wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:NES-ROB.jpg) under [CC-BY-SA](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.en).

Comment: 2014: Special advert made on request for [arqade](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/8066/8557) to be more gaming appropriate.