# Ninety days of Robotics Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Well, we've reached the 90 day mark, and even with it being bisected by the *Christmas and New Year lull*, I don't think we have done too badly.

[image: The first 90 days of Robotics Stack Exchange: 1.3 questions per day, 98% answered, 44 avid users, 791 total users, 2.3 answer ratio and 166 visits per day]

We are obviously a *slow burn* site, but have steadily been attracting new users and we are slowly regaining some of the momentum we lost in December, so we are looking good for the future.

What we need now is to get the word out, promote our community to others and get them coming here, asking questions and answering them. Hopefully, if we can get some [Community Promotion Ads](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/149/37) accepted on other sites in the stack exchange network, it might help us get noticed.

We also need to help define our community and answer [The 7 Essential Meta Questions for Robotics Stack Exchange](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/18/37).

So, Happy 3 month anniversary to all and thanks to everyone for their questions, answers, comments, votes and the time you've all spent here.

Answer (score 3):

Mark, thanks for all the work you've put in to get Robot.SE off the ground.

Regarding the points that need work, my feeling is that the problem might not be attracting new users, but convincing them it is worth sticking around. I get the feeling that most of the questions here are either too advanced/specific (likely the topic of current research) or too basic/broad (lacking core concepts related to the question or whose answers can only be opinions).

We basically need better questions and more people willing to give great answers for them. I ask myself whether we'll be able to reach proper balance between the PhD and DIY crowds. I surely hope so, and will be sticking around to help whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

Once immediate thing we can do is "spruce up" the site.  math.SE front page specifically has a welcome message outlining who they want to visit the site. So does cs.SE, etc. Where's ours?

I agree with [@georgebrindeiro](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156/ninety-days-of-robotics-stack-exchange/157#157). I think the problem is most people have a disconnect between what's possible and their expectations of a robot. I believe we can serve *both* the research-level *and* the DIY level people, since (hopefully) the researchers are just glorified DIYers. I think math.SE has the ideal crowd: active practitioners and interested beginners.

Comment: As I mentioned over at [Could we please edit our landing page / welcome note](http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/a/164/37), this is already shown if you aren't logged in.