# Six months of Robotics Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Well, we've reached the six month mark and we continue to have steady, if slow, overall growth.

[image: The first six months of Robotics Stack Exchange: 1.1 questions per day, 95% answered, 57 avid users, 1,192 total users, 2.1 answer ratio and 282 visits per day]

As I said [at 3 months](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/156/37), we seem to be a *slow burn* site, but while our questions per day, percentage answered and answer ratios have dropped *slightly*, our visits per day and user totals have been improving.

We still need to get the word out though, promote our community to others and get them coming here, asking questions and answering them. We also still need to help define our community and answer [The 7 Essential Meta Questions for Robotics Stack Exchange](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/18/37).

We now have [Community Promotion Ads](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/149/37) on several other sites in the stack exchange network, and get quite a lot of referrals from both stack overflow and google, which is a good sign.

So, Happy 6 month anniversary to all and thanks to everyone for their questions, answers, comments, votes and the time you've all spent here.

Comment: A note:After the initial month, drops are generally due to seasonal effects. For example, on Phys and Chem, we get spikes during examination time and plunges in the vacations after that. I wouldn't worry :)