# Do we have a 300x300 logo that we can use for ads on other stack exchanges?

Tags: discussion

This stack exchange is advertised here: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4675/science-stack-exchanges-helping-other-science-stack-exchanges, but the size is a little bit different from all the other SE's advertised there. Can someone switch it so that our logo is the same size as all the other ones?

Answer (score 1):

Lol I've never seen that graphic before. I have no idea where it came from. As far as I know, we don't have an "official" logo; our logo has always been (since I've been coming here, at least) an "Ro" in a blue speech bubble.

Answer (score 0):

The last time we solicited ideas for community ads. was [back in 2014](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/149/37) and the requirements back then were slightly different, which is why they are 220 x 250 rather than 300 x 250.

Now would be a great time to [help promote Robotics with Community Promotion Ads](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1393/37) however, so feel free to make some suggestions.

In the meantime, I will see if I can find my original source images and recreate my suggestions so they comply with the new requirements.

Comment: Thank you Mark Booth :)