# "Current state" questions

Tags: discussion, on-topic

We are starting to get a few questions a la "What is the current state of ...".

- [What is the current state of the Google Self Driving Car Project?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/403/131)
- [What is the state of subsumption architecture research?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/354/131)
- [Developing for 8-bit AVR-s, what are the current, open and free libraries out there?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/94/131) [closed]

I'm not sure how well suited these questions are as the information might be out of date quite quickly. I'm also wondering if we want to develop an official stance towards questions like that or whether other SE sites already have one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, questions like this should be closed as *too localised*, since this reason covers localised in time or situation as well as geographically localised.

From the [FAQ](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/faq) entry [Why are some questions closed?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/faq#close):

> - **too localized**
>
>   This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet. For help making this question more broadly applicable, [see the FAQ](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/faq#close).

<sup>(What a lovely self referential FAQ entry. *8')</sup>

Having said that, if a question can be made *less localised*, then we should endeavour to do so, as I have done in my suggested edit to [What is the state of subsumption architecture research?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/354/37) which I changed to [Is subsumption architecture still an active area of research?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/354/37). While it still isn't a great question and risks being answered with unqualified yes/no answers, it is better than being a *current state* question.

Comment: You may want to report the recursiveness on [MSO](meta.stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how "Is subsumption architecture still an active area of research is any less temporally bound than the original. The answer depends on when it's answered as much as the original.

I also don't see why "Developing for 8-bit AVR-s, what are the current, open and free libraries out there?" should be closed as temporally bounded (although it has several other problems justifying its closure). Leave out the word "current" and you have a very common type of question, and really, the word "current" is pretty much implied, e.g., on StackExchange, "what's a good php library for processing RSS feeds and converting to JSON?" would be a fine question.  It may not say "current", but no one is interested in out of date answers, and the correct answer may well change over time.

I think the "temporal bounds" guide needs to be applied much more lightly than the geographic bounds guides.