# What logo should we use after beta phase?

Tags: discussion, design

I would like to collect logo proposals for Robotics Stack Exchange, when it finished the beta phase. There are some rates we have to improve to achieve that, but anyway, it doesn't hurt to think about the design and logo today.

So I would like you to post your ideas and/or drafts for logos in the answers below. I will make the first step. There is no actual reasons to decide for a specific version at this moment, since we are a bit away from finishing beta phase, but I think it still makes sense to vote for logos and ideas you like and down vote those you can't think of being used.

Just to clarify, not only visual logo drafts but also single ideas written in words are welcome here.

Answer (score 3):

I vote for an abstract and clean overall design for Robotics Stack Exchange. This is my logo draft. Below there is logo and name in one line. But I also share a [link to the high resolution logo itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhq3H.png) with you.

[image: logo proposal for Robotics Stack Exchange]

A gear and a micro controller point out where robotics as a field is located, at the intersection of both engineering and programming and electronics. Therefore I think it can represent what our community is about in a clean way.

Comment: I like the logo, though I find it a bit hard to recognise the micro controller as such, I thought it was supposed to be an insect-like bot :)